# Ubuntu 19.10 use bluetooth headset with microphone

Tags: bluetooth, microphone

I have a head set with a microphone which connects with Bluetooth. I also have  jbl speaker with microphone in it. 
Both devices I can connect easy and the play sound.

But using the microphone does not work. I have read on forms that it will not work with the A2DP Sink configuration and I should use HSP/HFP. But when I do the sound output gets with a lot of cracks and after about 10 seconds it goes back to A2DP or the connection is lost.

Any idea how to make my Bluetooth mics working?

Comment: Please boot with a LiveUSB of a different version (19.04 or 18.04) of Ubuntu, and see if the problem persists, then click [edit] and tell us the result.